# Is the universe of ZFA rigid? The pairing axiom implies that even atoms have a unitary set which discern them from all other atoms. So, is it rigid?

Tags: set-theory

Although any permutation of atoms induces an automorphism of the whole universe, atoms seem to be indiscernible only within the permutation models. Can a permutation model be extended to a rigid structure? We can suppose that AC holds.

Answer (score 4):

You have answered your own question.

In ZFA, every definable permutation $\pi:A\to A$ of the class of atoms extends uniquely to an automorphism of the entire set-theoretic universe, simply by defining it on sets $y$ as follows:
$$\pi(y)=\{\pi(x)\mid x\in y\}.$$
It is easy to see that $x\in y\iff \pi(x)\in \pi(y)$, and so this is an isomorphism. (One needs to know that $\pi$ is definable in order to know that the extension is definable, which is needed in order to know that $\pi(y)$ is a set, etc.)

If there are at least two atoms, then we can define $\pi$ so as to swap them, fixing all other atoms, and this map will extend to a definable automorphism of $V$. So in ZFA, if there are at least two atoms, then the universe is not rigid.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The OP was asking about extensions that can impose rigidity, he suggested AC, but I think this is not enough, we need GC to make a theory with atoms rigid.

Comment: Yes, I had answered the question asked in the title "Is the universe of ZFA rigid". The OP seems to have asked a different question in the body of the post. But actually, I am unsure what that question in the body is asking. The claim that atoms are indiscernible only within the permutation models is incorrect. Also, under AC every set-sized structure can be trivially extended to a rigid structure, but it is unclear whether that is the kind of answer that is sought.

Comment: Thank you, Joel and Zuhair for the answers. Perhaps I was not clear in my question. In other words:  under AC in ZFA, does Joel and Palumbo's result that every set has a rigid relation also holds, that is, even for atoms? I guess that even a permutation model, which is a structure in ZFA, can be extended to a rigid structure. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry to insist, but I am in doubt about something you don't find in the books and seems to require the interpretation of a more experienced set theorist. In ZFA we have the pairing axiom, so we can form the unitary set {a} even if a is an atom. Why this fact would not tell us that the atoms can always be discerned from one another? Fraenkel took a collection of "distinct" atoms for his "cells". Then, under extensions of permutations, the atoms "are made" indiscernible within the model. But I think that they are not for someone living outside the Model. Any mistake in this reading?

Comment: In ZFA atoms are indiscernible in the sense that every assertion $\varphi$ expressible in the language of set theory that holds of one atom $\varphi(a)$ holds of all atoms $\varphi(b)$. You cannot tell them apart in the language of set theory. This is because there is an automorphism swapping $a$ and $b$, and automorphisms preserve truth.

Comment: Regarding your other question, if AC holds in the form of the WOP, asserting that every set has a well order, then of course we can place rigid relations on any set, since well orders are rigid. But one must be note that equivalent formulations of AC in the ZF context are not necessarily equivalent in the ZFA context, especially if one takes ZFA to be axiomatized with replacement instead of full collection. There is a discussion of this in my recent paper with Bokai Yao and in Yao's dissertation.

Comment: OK, thanks again. But I still think that being $a$ and $b$ distinct atoms, we can express in the language of ZFA the following assertion:  $x \in \{y\}$. Then $b \in \{b\}$ but $\neg(a \in \{b\})$. So, the given expression  distinguishes between atoms $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Joel, can you give me references for your paper with Bokai? Thanks.

Comment: Your property takes $b$ as a parameter. Obviously when one allows parameters, then no two distinct objects are ever indiscernible. I am the only person who is *me*.  Here is the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.09766. Follow the references for Yao's paper.

Comment: @DécioKrause, we say expression $\phi(x,y)$ distinguishes $a$ from $b$ in a rigid manner if it contains enough information to enforce a unique substitution pattern, for example $x=a$ and $y=b$. That is, $\phi(x,y)$ is only true when $x=a$ and $y=b$, so $(x=a, y=a); (x=b,y=b); (x=b,y=a)$ substitutions all would render $\phi(x,y)$ false! Example, $x \in y$ discriminates rigidly between $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @DécioKrause, cont... But the expression $x \in \{y\}$ doesn't do that for the case when both $a,b$ are empty. Since we can have $(x=a \land y=a)$ and also we can have $(x=b \land y=b)$, so it didn't enforce a specific substitution, so it is not rigid. Notice also that neither $a$ nor $b$ are in the signature of ZFC. If one of them was, for example $a$, then easily the expression $x=a$ would be rigid.

Comment: I don't agree with Zuhair's criterion. Rather, the usual definition is like this: objects $a$ and $b$ are *discernible* with respect to a language, if there is some property $\varphi(x)$ expressible in that language such that $\varphi(a)$ but not $\varphi(b)$. Otherwise, they are *indiscernible*.  An element $a$ is *definable*, in contrast, if it has some property $\varphi(a)$ that only $a$ has. In the real field $\langle\mathbb{R},+,\cdot\rangle$ the definable elements asre exactly the algebraic reals, but any two distinct real numbers are discernible, since there will be a rational between.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins. You are defining discernibility of $a$ and $b$ with respect to a *language*, while I was defining it with respect to a specific *expression* (i.e. a formula) of the language, so mine is piecemeal while yours is global. The difference is in the context. The only thing I tried to say is that if we are given a specific expression $\phi(x,y)$ and given two specific objects $a;b$ and $\phi(x,y)$ was true for more than one substitution pattern of its variables $x,y$ by $a,b$, then the expression $\phi$ doesn't rigidly discriminate between $a,b$, this a specific scenario.

Comment: Nice discussion, Joel and Zuhair. But let me go back to the specific case of the atoms in ZFA. Of course, atoms can be made indiscernible within a permutation model, as explained by you and as is part of the folklore. But even within the model, they are still distinct as elements of the universe of ZFA. So, what we have is a deformable structure (the permutation model) and then I ask you: can structures in ZFA also be extended to rigid structures as it happens in the pure ZFC?  Thanks for this one more. Best, DK.

Comment: You don't need a permutation model for indiscernibility. Atoms in ZFA are simply indiscernible, full stop. Every permutation of the atoms extends to an automorphism of the universe in ZFA, and so any statement made about any of the atoms holds equally of all other atoms. This is what it means to be indiscernible--there is no statement that distinguishes them. It has nothing to do with permutation models. Meanwhile, about the rigid relation principle, if you are speaking of structures within ZFA (not the universe of ZFA itself), then this is an immediate consequence of the axiom of choice.

Comment: If you augment ZFA with a global choice principle, in the form of global well-order of the universe, and you add this order to the language, then the ZFA universe becomes definably rigid, meaning that there would be no definable automorphisms as previously. Any such automorphism of the atoms, if it respected the global well order, would have to fix every atom and then by induction it would be the identity map on sets.